# How do I get a table that shows events per user over a time interval?

Tags: mysql, analytics, bigdata

This is very hard to explain in just one question, however here goes.

In MySQL database I have a table called video that has all the videos created.
The structure is something like this

```
id
owner
title
created_at
```

I have another table user, something like this

```
id
name
created_at
```

The goal is to get the following graph
[image]

x axis is the month #
y axis is the # of videos per month

As you can see, it shows how many videos each user created each month. BUT the first month is always 30 days from the date the user is created. So for user Ben it is going to be from 2016-10-01 to 2016-11-01 but for Rick it is from 2016-08-01 to 2016-09-01

So for Ben's first month it is different from the first month of Rick by approximately 60 days.

But in the graph I want to show all of them as month #1

My solution for now is to "normalize" the data. So to get the data for Ben I took the difference between a fixed date (I set it to 2016-01-01) and calculated the difference of days.

Then I subtract the number of days for all the videos and this way all the videos first month is going to be 2016-01-01 to 2016-02-01

This works, but I'm really not sure if this is the best approach.

Anyone with a better idea of how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: A friendly suggestion to use this kind of tool to display example data: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables .It really helps understand your data schema and make it more intuitive.

Comment: sound ok to me, but instead of using a fixed date I would use the `MIN(date)`

Answer (score 0):

I was told about a better way to do it.
Instead of normalizing the dates as I was doing, we just create a new property

I updated my `create_video` event to have a property like `age_of_user`. Then I can group_by `age_of_user` to see how many videos they uploaded in whatever number month.

Something like

```
{
    age_of_user: {
    days: 64,
    weeks: 9
    months: 2,
   }
}
```

Each event is created with this new property.
And when I query I group by month and by user and get all the data I need

This way I don't need to mess up with the timestamp of the video and I can use it in different queries.